# How many moderators will we have after the election?

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

How many mods will we have after the election?  In other words, are any mods planning on retiring?

Comment: I believe its 3. Undo will be standing for re-election. I'm not. I don't think Gilles is either.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks. I was not aware that the existing mods (such as yourself) do not automatically continue their role.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the mod election page, 3 moderators will be elected. The previous pro-tem team has the option of standing as moderators, but it looks like Undo's the only one of the old mods standing. He'll need to be voted in as per any other mod.